# Count continuously until cell value changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a work sheet with data like so:

```
A 
A 
A 
B 
B 
C 
D 
D
```

What I'd like to do is count each occurrence of A, B, and so on like so:

```
  A  1
  A  2
  A  3
  B  1
  B  2
  C  1
  D  1
  D  2
```

Is there any easy way to do this I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter
`=IFERROR(IF(A1=OFFSET(A1;-1;0);OFFSET(C1;-1;0)+1;1);1)`
into cell C1 (third column) and copy it down into all the remaining rows.

`IF(A1=OFFSET(A1;-1;0);...` attempts to compare the value in cell A1 and the cell above it (this will be valid for all cells from A2 and down).
If this fails (as it does on the first row), then `IFERROR(` will catch this and put the last `;1)` into the cell.
In other cases the `IF()` will complete, pick the value on the row above and add 1 if the A-column cell contents are equal, or just set it to `1` for differing content.